# Cocoa Unified (Login) Window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

How does one make a window like in the screen below? As you can see, the titlebar is merged with the window.

[image]

As an aside, does anyone know of a good open source application that has this kind of login window, so that I can inspect it and also see find some good alternative UI elements for username/password field and buttons.

Comment: @Abizern - don't think so, the InAppStoreWindow class still seems to treat the title bar as separate from the window background. So if you want a fluent gradient, it's not possible.

Comment: INAppStoreWindow has the ability to set a block for drawing the title area of the window, which would allow you to do a gradient from the top of the window to the bottom of the title bar. Then in your view code for the rest of the window draw a gradient starting with the color the gradient in the title bar ended at. Also, disable drawing of the baseline separator and you should have the effect you want

Answer (score 1):

If you use INAppStoreWindow you could replicate the effect of the window in your screenshot. As the window in your screenshot has a clearly delineated separation between the login fields and the new account section you could use the ability of INAppStoreWindow to draw a significantly larger title area than normal.

This would allow you to place the login fields in the "title" area of the window and the new account items in the normal area of the window.

With INAppStoreWindow you would want to create a separate view in interface builder that will be added as a titlebar subview that contains the login fields. Then you would use a custom title drawing block to draw the gradient from the top of the window down to the bottom of login custom view.

You would also want to disable the vertical centering of the "traffic control" button (close, minimize, zoom). To achieve the look of the custom controls, you could simply draw the style right into the window and then use borderless controls, which would give you the style you want for the text fields. For the buttons you would want to create custom subclasses to draw them in the styles you want.

For the bottom part of the window you would draw your gradient in the `drawRect:` method of your window view subclass.

https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow is where you will find INAppStoreWindow, I recommend reading the documentation. This window subclass will fully allow you to create the style of window in your screenshot!

Good luck! :)